# Proving that a mapping is a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $G$ is a group, and let $S(G)$ denote the group of bijections $G\rightarrow{G}$ under composition of maps.  Prove that the mapping ${\varphi}:G\rightarrow{S(G)}$ defined as follows is a group homomorphism. Every $a\in{G}$ is mapped to ${r_{a}}\in{S(G)}$ where ${r_{a}}(g) = ga$ for every $g\in{G}$. This mapping may be described as *the right translation by* $a\in{G}$. The analogous statement for left translations follows easily, but I am having trouble proving that ${\varphi}(ab) ={\varphi}(a){\varphi}(b)$. Thanks!

In light of the comment/solution posted by Edcookie 274, the definition of *right translation* by a group element should be $${\varphi}(a) = {r_{a}}(g) = ga^{-1}$$ for every $g\in G.$ This definition makes everything work easily and clears up all my questions.

Comment: For any $g\in G$, can you find what is $\varphi(ab)(g)$ and what is $[\varphi(a)\circ\varphi(b)](g)$?

Comment: You might be missing the equation $\phi(a)=r_a$. Once you have that, start substituting...

Comment: Mark, by my reckoning, ${\varphi}(ab)(g) = g(ab)$, while $[{\varphi}(a)\circ{\varphi}(b)](g) = {\varphi}(a)({\varphi}(b)(g)) = {\varphi}(a)(gb) =(gb)a=g(ba)$. I cannot see how these two elements are equal unless $ab = ba$.

Comment: Again, Lee, if ${\phi}(a) =r_{a}$, then ${\phi}(ab) =r_{ab}$, and ${\phi}(a){\phi}(b) = r_{a} r_{b}$. But then for any $g\in{G}$, $$r_{ab} (g) = g(ab),$$ while $$r_{a} r_{b} (g) = r_{a} (gb) = (gb)a =g(ba).$$ And I cannot see why these two elements are equal unless $ab = ba$.

Comment: The mapping that uses the right regular representation of g is actually {phi} (x) = p(x inverse). Try this one instead!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the definition of right translation should be ${\varphi}(a) = r_{a}$ where ${r_{a}}(g) = g(a^{-1}).$ In this case, for any $g\in G$, $${r_{ab}}(g)=g((ab)^{-1}) = g(b^{-1} a^{-1}) = r_{a}(g(b^{-1}) = r_{a}r_{b}(g).$$ SO IT WORKS!! This to me seems to be worthy of a solution. So I gave you an up vote.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi(ab):G\rightarrow G$ defined by $\varphi(ab)(g) = (ab)g = a(bg) = a(\varphi(b)(g)) = \varphi(a)\circ\varphi(b)(g) $

Comment: I gave you an up vote Daniele, but I made a typo mistake in my post, and given my mistake, your answer was correct. But the problem is that with right translation, the definition is ${\varphi}(a)(g) = ga$ by definition. And in this case, ${\varphi}(ab)(g) = g(ab)$, while ${\varphi}(a){\varphi}(b)(g) = {\varphi}(a)(gb) = (gb)a=g(ba)\neq g(ab)$ unless $ab=ba$ which we cannot assume in general.

Comment: The answer by Daniele proves that *left translation* is an injective group homomorphism $G\rightarrow{S(G)}.$ Daniele's proof is perfectly correct. But *right translation* by a group element is also an injective group homomorphism $G\rightarrow{S(G)}.$ Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $G$ is a group with identity element $e$, and let $S(G)$ be the group of bijections (equipped with the group law of composition of functions) $G\rightarrow{G}.$ Then the maps $G\rightarrow{S(G)},$ $a\mapsto{l_{a}},$ and $a\mapsto{r_{a}}$ where for any $g\in{G}$ $${l_{a}}(g) = ag,$$ and  $${r_{a}}(g) = ga^{-1}$$ are both injective group homomorphisms $G\rightarrow{S(G)}.$ They are injective because ${l_{a}} = {l_{b}}$ implies that ${l_{a}}(g) ={l_{b}}(g)$ for every $g\in{G}$, and in particular ${l_{a}}(e) =ae=a=b=be={l_{b}}(e)$, and ${r_{a}}={r_{b}}$ implies that ${r_{a}}(g)={r_{b}}(g)$  for every $g\in{G}$, and in particular, ${r_{a}}(e)= ae=a=b=be={r_{b}}(e)$. We also observe that for every $g\in{G},$ $${l_{ab}}(g)=abg=a(bg)=a({l_{b}}(g))={l_{a}}({l_{b}}(g))={{l_{a}}}\circ{{l_{b}}}(g),$$ while $${r_{ab}}(g)={g(ab)^{-1}}=g{b^{-1}}{a^{-1}}={r_{a}}(gb^{-1})={r_{a}}\circ{r_{b}}(g).$$
I am grateful to Daniele Tampieri and Edcookie274 for helping me clear this up.

Comment: If $G$ is a *finite* group, this argument (using either left or right translation) proves *Cayley's Theorem*: Every finite group of order $n$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of a finite symmetric group $S_{n}$ consisting of all $n!$ permutations of $n$ letters.